# Spring factory with custom constructors

Tags: java, spring, factory

I'm trying to create a factory pattern with Spring. I was able to create it using `FactoryBean`, like below:

*Serivce interface*

```
public interface MyService {
   void doProcess();
}
```

*Implementations*

```
 @Service(value = "fooMyService")
 @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
 public class FooMyServiceImpl implements MyService {

   @Override
   public void doProcess() {
     ...
   }

 }

@Service(value = "barMyService")
@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class BarMyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  @Override
  public void doProcess() {
    ...
  }

}
```

*Factory*

```
public interface MyServiceFactory {

  MyService getService(String serviceName);

}
```

*Factory configuration*

```
@Bean
public FactoryBean<?> myServiceFactoryBean() {
  ServiceLocatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setServiceLocatorInterface(MyServiceFactory.class);
  return factoryBean;
}
```

So, the code below calls the service

```
@Autowired
private MyServiceFactory myServiceFactory;  
...
MyService fooMyService = myServiceFactory.getService("fooMyService");
MyService barMyService = myServiceFactory.getService("barMyService");
```

What I need to do now, is to create a factory with custom constructors, that will be created at run time and inject in beans.

Is this possible in Spring?